# PHP equivalent for Java MessageDigest

Tags: java, php, hash, cryptography

I'm trying to get an implementation for Java function in PHP. Essentially the MessageDigest Java Class.

I'm a bit new to cryptography so i'd like to understand why the eventual solution works in detail.

ok so this is the Java code

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

String password = "xxxxxxx";
MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("sha-256");
m.update(password.getBytes(), 0, password.length());
return new BigInteger(1, m.digest()).toString(16);
```

Currently in PHP i am doing

```
use phpseclib\Math\BigInteger as Math_BigInteger;

$password = "xxxxxxx";
$sha_password = hash('sha256', unpack("C*",$password), true);
return new Math_BigInteger($sha_password, 16);
```

Currently this will not have same output, some help please... and why?

Answer (score 3):

Your Java code has a bug in this line:

```
m.update(password.getBytes(), 0, password.length());
```

The byte representation of a string does not necessarily have the same number of bytes as the number of characters in a string. Since Unicode is used a single character can be encoded into multiple bytes. In order to use the whole password and not just a part of it, use the following instead:

```
m.update(password.getBytes());
```

But this is still not enough, because your Java code might behave differently in different environments. You need to specify the encoding explicitly. In my tests `m.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));` worked well to establish compatibility with PHP code.

Since your Java code produces a hex-encoded digest, you should use the following PHP code:

```
$password = "xxxxxxx";
$sha_password = hash('sha256', $password, false);
```

which produces

```
7b70d3ab4c7641542e1f158b458eeae7cfb7bdb815d4110cc6178bafcfdf43f8
```

---

Security considerations:

Running a password through a single round of hashing is usually not enough. Today's brute forcers are able to check billions of passwords per second. You should either use PBKDF2 or scrypt depending on your use case.